# How to keep current wizard view after calling python code in odoo 10?

Tags: odoo

i am setting up a wizard form view where many2many fields are showing in tree which is needed to editable. after each record there is a Button. When clicking on button , it will redirect to model's main form view.
I need to keep current wizard open after making changes and clicking on **Change** Button against each editable record. How can i do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Basically the wizard doesn't close, if you are calling any function through that wizard, try calling the wizard view again in the change button action.

Answer (score 0):

Default behavior of a wizard is to close upon the pressing of any button and execution of the function associated with that button.

You need to do is to bring up the exact same wizard when your button is pressed with your desired values.

```
def your_method(self):
    form_view_id = self.env.ref('module.form_view').id
    # your logics

       return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'name': 'some name',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'wizard.model',
            'views': [[form_view_id, "form"]],
            'res_id': self.id,
            'context': context,
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I only had to change `@api.one` to `@api.multi`.

Using `@api.one` return to main screen and did not show the form view.